# How to have ranges in a SWITCH statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Switch statement that tests for a range of values. Unfortunately, when it detects a compliant value, it hops out of the Switch statement and doesn't iterate through completely, making the data not necessarily correct. How can I process the entire Switch statement?

This is my Switch statement

```
Switch ((Score= 0.00), 1, (Score >0.00 & Score < (1/2)), 2, (Score >= 0.50 & Score < (2/3)), 3, (Score >= (2/3) & Score < 1.00), 4, true, 5) AS TotalScore
```

The problem is when I have a value, say 0.60. The value should be 3 (since it is greater than 0.50 but less than 0.67) However, since 0.60 is > 0.00, I am assuming it is setting the TotalScore to 2 instead, since that is what I get.

How do I write a Switch statement that fields a range of values and handles these in-betweens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a string concatenation operator in MS Access.  So, it is not appropriate when you intend `AND`.

In your case, you can simplify the logic:

```
Switch(Score = 0.00, 1,
       Score < 1.0/2, 2, 
       Score < 2.0/3, 3,
       Score < 1.00), 4,
       true, 5) AS TotalScore
```

`switch` evaluates the conditions in order, so it stops at the first matching one.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just needed to start at the highest value and go down:

```
Switch (Score>= 1, 5, Score >= (2/3), 4, Score>= 0.50,  3, Score> 0, 2, Score= 0, 1) AS TotalScore
```

Comment: Also, `&` is not a logical operator, it's `And`.